# JS number function adds up zeros at the end

Tags: javascript

I am using the `Number()` JS function which is supposed to convert string value to numeric.

It's working fine for small numbers. For big ones - it is starting to substitude values with zeros as shown on the image:

[image]

Is there a work around for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JS,  the largest integral value is `9007199254740991` That is, all the positive and negative integers should not exceed the `-9007199254740991` and `9007199254740991` respectively.

The same is defined as the 2<sup>53</sup>-1.

```js
console.log(Number.isSafeInteger(parseInt('1111111111')))
console.log(parseInt('1111111111'))
console.log(Number.isSafeInteger(parseInt('111111111111111111')))
console.log(parseInt('111111111111111111'))
//9007199254740991 - The largest JS Number
console.log(Number.isSafeInteger(parseInt('9007199254740991')))
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because you're using numbers that are larger than [`Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) and Javascript does not guarantee to represent these numbers correctly

Use `Number.isSafeInteger` to check:

```
> Number.isSafeInteger(Number('111111111111111111'))
< false
```